# swagger ui authorize button not visible in laravel project

Tags: laravel, swagger-ui, laravel-7, swagger-php

I am working on a Laravel 7 project, and I used the package [dagbouj-hatem/swaggervel](https://packagist.org/packages/dagbouj-hatem/swaggervel):

[image]

and I had this swagger interface: so I'm looking for a solution to display the swagger authorize button and implement the basic auth with bearer token.

thank you in advance.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama yes, you can activated it with this configuration in your  `AppBaseController` :

Comment: `/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *   basePath="/api/v1",
 *   schemes={"http","https"},
 *   @SWG\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityDefinition="Bearer",
 *      type="apiKey",
 *      name="Authorization",
 *      in="header"
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Info(
 *     title="REST API Docs",
 *     description="REST API Docs.",
 *     version="1.0.0",
 *   )
 * )
 */
class AppBaseController extends Controller
{ ......`